# Ошибка cannot open source file "stdafx.h"

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Мне достались исходники небольшого проекта из нескольких файлов. При открытии его в visual studio еще до начала компиляции в редакторе кода в каждом файле подчеркивается строка

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

Пишет:

> cannot open source file "stdafx.h"

Сами файлы stdafx.h и stdafx.cpp присутствуют в директории проекта. 
1. Как решить проблему?
2. Может ли эта проблема возникать из-за того, например, что проект был сделал в одной версии vs, а я открываю его в другой? Если да, как узнать исходную версию студии? Доступа к разработчикам проекта у меня нету.
Спасибо.

Comment: Для начала скажите, находится ли этот файл в той же директории, что и cpp файлы, в котрых он заинклюжен?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch да, файлы находятся в директории проекта

Comment: вопрос пожалуйста перечитаете. Я не спрашивал, находится ли этот файл в каталоге проекта (вы это итак в вопросе указали), я спросил: находится ли stdafx.h в ТОЙ ЖЕ директории, что и CPP файлы, в которых есть этот инклюд?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Действительно, часть файлов .cpp находится в папке, где и .sln. В ней же находится и stdafx.h и stdafx.cpp. В этих .cpp файлах строка #include "stdafx.h" не подчеркивается. Другая часть .cpp файлов находится в подкаталоге. И в них подчеркивает #include "stdafx.h". Методом научного тыка указал полный адрес к файлу "d:\...\stdafx.h". Подчеркивание исчезло. Это правильный способ или надо делать по-другому? Почему так происходит, могли бы пояснить?

Comment: Дело в том, что компиляция не происходит по волшебству: компилятору нужны ваши cpp файлы, а в них заинклюжены хэдэры. При этом нужно понимать что впроцессе компиляции (на этапу препроцессора) эти инклюды заменяются на содержимое хэдэр файлов (препроцессор буквально копирует все их содержимое в cpp файл). А как он это сделает, если не знает где искать этот файл? Если вы используете ковычки, то это означает, что компилятор будет искать эти файлы в текущем катологе (там где cpp файл), а потом в системных путях. Поэтому нужно явно указать компилятору где нужно искать с помощью флага `-I`

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, я понял. Как вариант, оставить #include "stdafx.h", а в свойствах проекта в include directory указать путь к папке с заголовочными файлами. Какой из этих способов правильнее? Или есть еще варианты?

Comment: правильный - не указывать относительные пути к хэдэру в cpp файле.

Comment: не вижу на то причины.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, Хм, создал другой проект console application. в папке появились stdafx.cpp, файл main.cpp и, соответственно, их заголовочные файлы. в main.cpp есть строка #include "stdafx.h". все хорошо компилируется. затем добавляю в ту же папку sec.cpp и sec.h. в их файлах так же есть строка #include "stdafx.h". все компилируется. если же я создаю в директории проекта папку dir и помещаю туда файлы sec.cpp и sec.h. то строка #include "stdafx.h" в этих файлах уже подчеркивается. Указание полного пути, или относительного "../stdafx.h" убирает подчеркивание. Но ошибка остается при компиляции

Comment: да безразницы что там "подчеркивается" а что нет - это зависит от IDE, а не от языка или компилятора. Сборка должна проходить верно.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, при компиляции появляется ошибка
Error 2 error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "StdAfx.h"' to your source? d:\pr1\pr1\dir\sec.cpp 2 1 Pr1

Comment: вам же пишет: unexpected end of file - это означает, что вы где-то пропустили скобку, кавычку или что-то вроде того. И я уже писал, что указывать относительный и тем боллее абсолютный путь при инклюде - в корне не верно( а во втором случае и ошибочно).

Comment: Вы лучше содержимое этих `stdafx.*` файлов покажите. Может и не нужны они вовсе, так просто убрать упоминание инклюдов и дело в шляпе.

Comment: @älёxölüt а вам не кажется, что это зависит не от содержимого этого файла, а от содержимого остальных файлов проекта?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch что "это"?

Comment: @älёxölüt "ненужность" файлов stdafx.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, в проект не включены `stdafx.h` и возможно, `stdafx.cpp`.

> 1. Как решить проблему?

Добавьте `stdafx.h` и `stdafx.cpp` в проект. Выберите `Project / Add Existing Item...` и добавьте.

> 2. Может ли эта проблема возникать из-за того, например, что проект был сделал в одной версии vs, а я открываю его в другой?

Не может.

> Если да, как узнать исходную версию студии?

Из исходного (неконвертированного) файла проекта. В VS 6.0, к примеру, это `проект.dsp`. В VS2008 это `проект.vcproj`, В VS2017 это `проект.vcxproj`.

UPD Ответ на вопрос в комментариях:

> если же я создаю в директории проекта папку dir и помещаю туда файлы
>   sec.cpp и sec.h. то строка #include "stdafx.h" в этих файлах уже
>   подчеркивается. как быть?

Нужно указать относительный путь к `stdafx.h`, то есть `#include "..\stdafx.h"`.

Даже в достаточно большом проекте нет необходимости в подкаталогах. Реально они нужны в достаточно редких случаях, например, отделить файлы сторонних производителей. Для логического разбиения надо использовать подкаталоги проекта, а не файловые. VS стандартно создает `Include/Source/Resource`, но вам же никто не запрещает создать вместо них свои.

Comment: "Добавьте stdafx.h и stdafx.cpp в проект. Выберите Project / Add Existing Item... и добавьте." - файлы изначально присутствуют

Comment: @pucher, они присутствуют физически в каталоге проекта, или они присутствуют в проекте? Это не одно и то же. Если они присутствуют именно в проекте, посмотрите их свойства - куда ведет ссылка, в какой каталог? Попробуйте исключить (не удалить!) их из проекта и добавить заново.

Comment: Часть файлов .cpp находится в папке, где и .sln. В ней же находится и stdafx.h и stdafx.cpp. В этих .cpp файлах строка #include "stdafx.h" не подчеркивается. Другая часть .cpp файлов находится в подкаталоге. И в них подчеркивает #include "stdafx.h". Методом научного тыка указал полный адрес к файлу "d:\...\stdafx.h". Подчеркивание исчезло. Так правильно делать? Или как-то по-другому? И еще, вы сказали в свойствах файлов посмотреть их расположение. Все свойства облазил, но информации о пути не нашел. Как это сделать?

Comment: Не надо указывать полный адрес, я же написал вам как нужно сделать. Перенесите файлы в правильное место, к остальным файлам проекта. Если не поможет, исключите их из проекта и добавьте заново.

Comment: Добавление `.h` файла в проект никак не помогает компилятору находить этот файл. С точки зрения компиляции нет никакого смысла добавлять `.h` файлы в проект. Это ни на что не влияет. Добавление `.h` файлов в проект несет чисто косметический смысл - они появляются в панели слева и их можно открывать через эту панель. Решать исходную проблему "добавлением файлов в проект" бесполезно.

Comment: @freim, хотите сказать, все .cpp файлы должны находится в одной папке? А если проект большой? Мне пока помогло или указание полного пути к файлу или в свойствах проекта указал директорию с этими заголовочными файлами

Comment: @pucher, нет, `.cpp` могут находиться в разных папках, это нормально. Но файлу `stdafx.cpp` проекта место в папке проекта, и уж точно не в общей папке солюшена.

Comment: @AnT, верно, проект будет компилироваться даже если `.h` в проект не добавлены. Но есть одно исключение, и как раз оно здесь обсуждается. `stdafx.h` в проекте должен присутствовать, поскольку он фигурирует в настройках проекта.

Comment: @freim, создал проект console application. в папке появились stdafx.cpp,  файл main.cpp и, соответственно, их заголовочные файлы. в main.cpp есть строка  #include "stdafx.h". все хорошо компилируется. затем добавляю в ту же папку sec.cpp и sec.h. в их файлах так же есть строка  #include "stdafx.h". все компилируется. если же я создаю в директории проекта папку dir и помещаю туда файлы sec.cpp и sec.h. то строка #include "stdafx.h" в этих файлах уже подчеркивается. как быть?

Comment: @pucher, дополнил ответ. Откровенно говоря, на вопросы подобного уровня уже и отвечать не хочется. Ну неужели самому трудно додуматься, что если файл переносится в другое место, то надо и пути изменить?

Comment: @freim, ни один из вариантов: #include "../stdafx.h", #include "..\stdafx.h", #include "D:\\Pr1\\Pr1\\stdafx.h", #include "D:/Pr1/Pr1/stdafx.h" не помог. Подчеркивания нет, но ошибка при компиляции "Error 2 error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "StdAfx.h"' to your source? d:\pr1\pr1\dir\sec.cpp 2 1 Pr1"

Comment: @pucher, это уже другая [ошибка](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/fatal-error-c1010?view=vs-2017), прочитайте про нее, пожалуйста, и проверьте все ли правильно в настройках проекта "Precompiled headers", а потом сделайте Rebuild.